# What method should I use to get 3 different nodes (XML) from a data set (SQL)?

Tags: vb.net

I have a `DataSet` (in VB.NET) that has columns in place that I have pulled from a SQL database. My process now creates a new XML file per `DataRow` using a for-each loop.

**NODE 1**

```
Burt_Order> <Insert_Order AdOrderNumber="0000222861" AoAdOrder_ID="81772" Burt_SalesRep="ENERESJ" SalesRep="ENERESJ" MailCount="0" NonSubCount="0" DealerCount="0" SubscribCount="75753200" QuantityExpected="75753200" QuantityBilled="7575300" Product="Saturation StarTribune" AoPrpRunSchedule_Notes="" AoPrpRunSchedule_ID="12333" Pagecount="2" Sides="1" Color="" AdID="12333" OrderNotes="" AoAdOrder_LastEditDate="2015-10-06 17:45:50.457" OrderCreateDate="9/29/2015 3:12:53 PM" Internalstatus="1"/>
```

**NODE 2**

```
<Insert_Order_Zone Order_Zone="55344ZX_HD"/> 
<Insert_Order_Zone Order_Zone="55342X_HD"/> 
<Insert_Order_Zone Order_Zone="55312X_HD"/>
(Note: these all would share the same AoAdOrder_ID then a different AoAdOrder_ID would give me a different XML doc with ZIPS that share that same AoAdOrder_ID)
<Insert_Order_Zone Order_Zone="57342X_HD"/> 
<Insert_Order_Zone Order_Zone="55322X_HD"/>
```

**NODE 3**

```
<Insert_Order_Billing Price="610.47"/>
```

How can I create a process that creates a separate XML file for each unique `Order_Id`?

```
Main Process
For Each dr As DataRow In ds_AtexData.Tables("t_AtexData").Rows
                If dr.Item("PROCESSED FLAG") = 0 Then
                    Establish_OutputFile()
                    CreateXMLFileToBurt(dr)
                End If
            Next
 Public Sub CreateXMLFileToBurt(ByRef dr)
        Try
            JobLogger.Write("STARTING CreateXMLFileToBurt() ")
            'Delete the XML file if it already exists
            'If File.Exists(str_OutFileName) Then
            '    Kill(str_OutFileName)
            'End If

            xmlWSetting.Indent = True
            o_xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(XMLdirectory & timeofrun.Substring(0, 10).Replace("/", "") & "_" & timeofrun.Substring(11, 8).Replace(":", "") & "_" & xmlfilenumber & "_" & str_OutFileName, xmlWSetting)

            'Start writing out XML
            o_xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
            o_xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Burt_Order") 'root

            For Each dsaf As DataRow In ds_AtexData.Tables("t_AtexData").Rows   'REMOVE REMOVE REMOVE REMOVE REMOVE REMOVE REMOVE REMOVE REMOVE 
            Next
            'o_xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
            'o_xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Burt_Order") 'root

            o_xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Insert_Order")
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Internal_status", dr.Item("Internalstatus"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Order_Create_Date", dr.Item("OrderCreateDate"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("AoAdOrder_LastEditDate", dr.Item("AoAdOrder_LastEditDate"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Order_Notes", dr.Item("OrderNotes"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("AdID", dr.Item("AdID"))
            'o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Color", dr.Item("Color"))
            'o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Sides", dr.Item("Sides"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Page_Count", dr.Item("Pagecount"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Page_Type", dr.item("Page_Type"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("AoPrpRunSchedule_ID", dr.Item("AoPrpRunSchedule_ID"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("AoPrpRunSchedule_Notes", dr.Item("AoPrpRunSchedule_Notes"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Product", dr.Item("Product"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("QuantityBilled", dr.Item("QuantityBilled"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("QuantityExpected", dr.Item("QuantityExpected"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("SubscribCount", dr.Item("SubscribCount"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("DealerCount", dr.Item("DealerCount"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("NonSubCount", dr.Item("NonSubCount"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("MailCount", dr.Item("MailCount"))         '                              o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("", dr.item(""))
            'o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("SalesRep", dr.item("SalesRep"))
            'o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Burt_SalesRep", dr.item("SalesRep"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("AoAdOrder_ID", dr.item("AoAdOrder_ID"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("AdOrderNumber", dr.item("AdOrderNumber"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Weight", dr.item("Weight"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() 'Insert_Order

            'For Each dr2 As DataRow In ds_AtexData.Tables("t_atexdata").Rows            '
            '    For Each dr3 As DataRow In ds_AtexData.Tables("t_atexdata").Rows           '
            If dr.Item("AdOrderNumber") = dr2.Item("AdOrderNumber") AndAlso dr2.Item("FLAG") = 0 Then
                o_xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Insert_Order_Zone")
                dr2.Item("FLAG") = 1
                o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Order_Zone", dr.Item("Order_Zone"))
                o_xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() 'Insert_Order_Zone
            End If  '
                  '
            o_xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Insert_Order_Billing")
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Price", dr.Item("Price"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Bill_Quantity", dr.item("QuantityBilled"))
            o_xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() 'Insert_Order_Billing

            'Next

            'ElseIf ds_AtexData.Tables("t_AtexData").Rows.Count = 0 Then
            'o_xmlWriter.WriteRaw("There are no orders to be processed at this time.")
            'End If
            o_xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() 'end root
            o_xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()
            o_xmlWriter.Close()

            'Next

            'o_xmlWriter.Close()

            JobLogger.Write("COMPLETED CreateXMLFileToBurt() ")
            JobLogger.Write("...")
        Catch ex As Exception
            JobLogger.Write("****  ERROR ***** " & ex.ToString.Trim)
            Throw New AT_Application_Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Show the code for your current process.

Comment: Sorry, I put code in comments, hence "noob"

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the Select method of your DataTable so you can filter and sort your dataset.

( A link for reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w(v=vs.110).aspx )

If I understand what you're trying to do, you want to write a separate XML file for each AoAdOrderID, and have three nodes.

If you use the select method and filter to what you want from the table (like "FLAG" = 0... etc) and then sort by AoAdOrderID, you can then loop through your rows.

```
Dim expression As String = "FLAG = 0"
Dim sortOrder As String = "AoAdOrderID"
Dim foundRows As DataRow() = ds_AtexData.Tables("t_AtexData").Select(expression, sortorder)
```

In your loop you check for a change in AoAdOrderID.  If it changes, you close the previous file and start the next one.

Again, I'm not sure if that's what you're trying to do.  If not, maybe clarify what your objective is and I'll see if I can help.